# Is there a Grid Alignment System in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, grid, alignment, dock

I was wondering whether anyone knew of a JavaScript alignment system like the one on this page: http://trilancer.com/jpolite2/index1.html where you can drag the modules on the page into place?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you want to use something like that one? was quite buggy for me. Chrome 14.0 Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Sortable provides something pretty close to this.

See the portlets demo **[here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets)**.